# JS "for (var key in arr)" > throws my own Array.prototypes, but not the inherent ones. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iteration, prototype

I accidently used an iteration like

```
for (var key in arr)
{
    alert(key);
}
```

and got an output that rose some questions. (I wanted to iterate through a JSON, so I used 'key' - an 'i' for index would be more suitable in this case, no question :-)

The first outputs were the indeces (like '0', '1' etc.) - still no question - but at last it throws the names of my Array.prototypes, I declared somewhere else in the code. Prototypes like

```
Array.prototype.lastIndex = function(){
    return this.length - 1;
}
```

and it throws just 'lastIndex'.

What I don't understand: Are my own, non-inherent prototypes distinct from the JS-inherent ones like splice(), slice() ... ?

And: Why does it throw them at all? They are part of the Array.prototype, but not of a particular Array object!?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you attach a property to an object, by default, the property will be `enumerable`.
2. If a property is enumerable, `for..in` will pick it up.

So, when you are iterating an array object with `for..in`, it first gives all the enumerable properties in the current object. Then, it goes up the prototype chain and gives all the enumerable properties of the corresponding objects. So, in your case, it goes up the chain and finds an enumerable property called `lastIndex` in `Array`'s prototype, includes that in the iteration.

If you define it with `enumerable: false`, like this

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'lastIndex', {
    value: function() {
        return this.length - 1;
    },
    enumerable: false
});
```

it wont show up in `for..in` iterations. Quoting [MDN documentation for `enumerable` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Enumerable_attribute),

> The `enumerable` property attribute defines whether the property shows up in a `for...in` loop and `Object.keys()` or not.

**Note:** [Always use normal `for` loops for array iterations.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in)

Comment: Ok, so the JS-inherent Prototype properties all seem to be defined with enumerable:false.

Comment: note that you can omit "  enumerable: false" because false is the default. you need only explictly use "enumerable: true" when apropos. just a note, not a complaint...

Comment: @dandavis Correct, but I was trying to make a point in the answer. So, I thought that it would be better if it is explicit :-)

Answer (score 1):

Any array instances *inherits* from `Array.prototype`. So any change to the prototype will be reflected in those array *instances* as well.

If you wanted it to remain only to `arr` you would attach the function `lastIndex` just to it, so other array *instances* won't get affected.

So it appears in `for..in` loop, which iterates through enumerable properties, as `lastIndex` is an enumerable property.

Comment: Ya, 'instance' is the right term to distinguish it from prototype objects *thumbsup*